# How does 'Open with' a custom executable in Linux work?

Tags: bash, ruby, mime-types

I have a file called `foo.txt`. I want to associate my own program with the mime-type `.txt` so that my program opens a terminal and shows the contents of `foo.txt` as standard output. I would prefer Ruby, but BASH scripting will also be OK.

An working example: I can open an HTML file with `firefox`. I want to open `txt` files with my own executable the same way.

I can't figure out how can I actually get it working?

Example 2: I can open a `.txt` file with Geany/Mousepad/Atom/Code etc.
Let's suppose I have made a tool just like mousepad. How should my program handle the `.txt` mimetype?

So far I have made a small GUI program with Ruby and made it executable and tried to open `foo.txt` with my program (I used the Nemo file manager). I have captured arguments, and stdins in my Ruby program so it will show the Argument and STDINs if any. But my program doesn't even show up the window  if I open a `.txt` file with it!

How am I supposed to achieve the result?

Comment: To be clear, you have right clicked on the file and selected Open With > Other Application and selected your custom application and that does not work? What happens specifically? When you use your custom application can you open files with it?

Comment: Yes. I am using a simple Ruby GUI program (with Ruby2D) The custom command is a GUI application that shows the arguments given, the base name of the script. It runs normally from the terminal, but doesn't open when I 'open as' with that. Also, I have proper permissions, and I am using a single user.

Comment: What operating system are you using? You may need to change the values or import them from `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` to have Nemo recognize the change.

Comment: I am on Arch Linux (I use it on my laptop, desktop, and raspberry pi). That shouldn't matter much since I am using high level programming languages like Ruby and BASH here. The problem is not about mimetypes. I wanted to know if I can make my own executable program so that whenever I open a text file it will open my executable, and my executable will open a terminal and show the contents. That is to say, how does opening an app like that work? Should I work with STDINS or Arguments? So far my program (Ruby GUI with Ruby2D) doesn't even run whenever I open a text with my program.

Comment: Your Ruby GUI program is able to open up files, its Nemo not opening said files using your choice of filetype association? Is that the issue? Or is the issue that your Ruby program does not open up files? If the latter is the issue this question would be better served on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I want to open a txt file with my own Ruby or BASH program. I want to know how opening files like this should be handled in Ruby or BASH.

Comment: Example: You can open a .txt file with mousepad editor. The question is how mousepad text editor gets to know which file I want to open? How does 'open as'  really work?

Comment: Please edit your question to to be of that. As it stands now it seems like you are having issues with default program file type associations with Nemo. This is a complicated [subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495283/what-does-opening-a-file-actually-do) so it will best serve your needs to have your question be as clear as possible. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I can't call it an exact duplicate since I want to work with either BASH or Ruby. I would prefer Ruby, but if someone can answer in BASH, I will translate it to Ruby. But I won't prefer any other binaries. I want a simple example of a program that will open a .txt and it will show the name or contents of the text file.

Comment: If "Opens a terminal and shows the contents of `foo.txt` as standard output" are all done inside your program, and your program support command line parameters like `program filename`, then you can simply create a desktop file for your program, and set mime association through your DE settings.

Comment: Nah, that's kind of cheating and getting the job done. I am doing these things just to learn how to handle mimetypes with Ruby!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Introduction

When a file is opened with an application, the file is just passed to the application as an argument.

So when you open **firefox-nightly** located in `/bin/` with `p.html` located in `/home/user/`, it's basically similar to run `/bin/firefox-nightly /home/user/p.html`.

### Creating an Executable

As mentioned in the question:

> So far I have made a small GUI program with Ruby and made it
>   executable and tried to open foo.txt with my program (I used the Nemo
>   file manager).

Let us create a Ruby program as asked by the OP that will copy the contents of a file passed as an argument to `/tmp/tempfile-#{n}`. Note that any programming language will work if it can accept command line arguments.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# Errors
ERR_NO_FILE = 2

FILE = $*[0]

begin
    tempfile, counter = File.join(%W(/ tmp tempfile)), 0
    tempfile.replace(File.join(%W(/ tmp tempfile-#{counter += 1}))) while File.exist?(tempfile)
    IO.write(tempfile, IO.read(FILE))
rescue Errno::ENOENT
    exit!(ERR_NO_FILE)
rescue Interrupt, SystemExit, SignalException
    exit!(0)
rescue Exception
    abort($!.backtrace.join(?\n))
end if FILE
```

And let's call our program *copycat.rb*, and move it to /tmp/ directory.

We can surely run the program on a terminal like this:

```
/tmp/copycat.rb /tmp/AFile
```

A this will copy all the contents of `/tmp/AFile` to `/tmp/tempfile-#{n}`
Where `#{n}` is the count in case any duplicate tempfile exists.

### Creating an Application Entry

Now to open this with our program from the file manager, we need to create an Application entry. To do that, we have 2 options. The **first options is**:

Create a file called copycat.desktop in `$HOME/.local/share/applications`, with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=CopyCat
Comment=Copy the contents of a file to /tmp/tempfile#{n}
Exec=/tmp/copycat.rb %u
Icon=edit-copy
Path=
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
Actions=
Categories=Copy;Utility
```

Don't forget to add the `%u` option to the line starts with Exec.

### Testing

Well, to test, let's create a simple file called with the content 'hello world' or anything you want. Open your file manager, and click your secondary mouse button on the file, and select "Open With" or similar option. Because it's GUI related, I will add some sample pictures.

1. Nautilus, "Open With Other Application":

   [image: Nautilus, "Open With Other Application"]
2. Nautilus, "View All Applications":

   [image: Nautilus, "View All Applications"]
3. "CopyCat":

   [image: "CopyCat"]
4. When done, you can see the `tempfile-#{n}` created in `/tmp/`

   [image]

The file manager I used here is Nautilus, but this should work with other file managers as well, just the text might differ.

The **second option is** to make the application available for all users. To do that, you have to move the file from `$HOME/.local/share/applications/copycat.desktop` to `/usr/share/applications` and change the ownership to root.

This is how the open with a custom executable works in Linux.
A similar GUI app can be created and opened in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

```
case $1 in
 *txt)  applic=less ;;
 *html) applic=vim  ;;
esac

xterm -e $applic $1 &
```

Minimalistic, but tested.

This script you can call from a first xterm. Dont look at the `case-esac`, but note `xterm` with `-e` and ampersand.